# Generate where clause using MessageFormat

Tags: java, string, messageformat

I want to generate SQL using MessageFormat so that same string can be used by many users and they just have to pass where clause arguments.

e.g. I want select * from user where name='John' and age=15 and area='JStreet'

I can do it using MessageFormat.format(select * from user where {0}={1} and {2}={3} and {4}={5} ,"name","'John'", "age","15","area","'JStreet'")

But I want it dynamic. Means here I am bounded till {0}-{5} what if I need to add more AND conditions.
How can I do this ?

Comment: do you want to use prepared statements ?

Comment: No. As of now I want it in above format only as our query tool is not proper SQL supported.

Comment: This is a very dangerous thing to do. Don't let the user control the kind of strings that are part of your SQL statement. If you have to, let the user pick columns and make sure the column names are valid column names in the table, then dynamically build a prepared statement and fill the values.

Comment: My bad but it will be handled by program based on diff scenario. So no need to worry about security and its for internal use only. Hence I am exploring this way.

Answer (score 0):

Do not let the user specify the column names as strings.  That makes your code easy to break, and it opens you to a very common and dangerous security vulnerability known as SQL injection.  I know you said it’s only “for internal use,” but employees/students can be hackers and it’s always possible one will wish to cause harm.

Instead, represent the columns as enum values.  I assume the columns of the `user` table are fixed, so you can hard-code them in the enum:

```
public enum UserField {
    NAME,
    AGE,
    AREA
}
```

As others have mentioned, always use a PreparedStatement when making use of values from end users or from unknown code.  You can now use the enums to build that PreparedStatement:

```
public PreparedStatement createStatement(Map<UserField, ?> values,
                                         Connection conn)
throws SQLException {

    Collection<String> tests = new ArrayList<>(values.size());
    for (UserField field : values.keySet()) {
        tests.add(field.name().toLowerCase() + "=?");
    }

    String sql;
    if (tests.isEmpty()) {
        sql = "select * from user";
    } else {
        sql = "select * from user where " + String.join(" and ", tests);
    }

    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    int index = 0;
    for (Object value : values) {
        statement.setObject(++index, value);
    }

    return statement;
}
```